# .NET DataAnnotations - StringLength and MinimumLength

Tags: .net, data-annotations

I want to use a data annotation that looks something like this:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a review of at least 20 characters")]
    [StringLength(?????, MinimumLength = 20, ErrorMessage = "The tour location must be at least 20 characters")]
    public string Review { get; set; }
```

I'd like to somehow indicate there is no maximum length, just a minimum length. What would I enter for the first attribute value to indicate no maximum length? Of course, I could use something like 999999999 which essentially does the same thing, but there must be a more standard way.

Comment: `int.MaxValue` will work. However, it might also get you in trouble if the data annotations are used for e.g. creating a database - for example, if the database engine doesn't support string columns `int.MaxValue` long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`MaxLength` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute.maximumlength(v=vs.110).aspx) is a set in the [constructor of `StringLengthAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute.stringlengthattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). You can't *not-set* it.

You could create your own attribute implementation, but that's overkill.
You could inherit, and implement an attribute that sets the *MaxLength* to a default maximum value.

Or... You could simply do:

```
[StringLength(Int32.MaxValue, MinimumLength = 20, ErrorMessage = "The tour location must be at least 20 characters")]
```

That's essentially what you suggested with *999999999*, but at least it looks more intentional and leaves no room for errors (100000000 or above...).